# Javascript arrays manipulations

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am struggling.
here is the small challenge. I have three arrays

```
let arr1 = ["one", "un", "ray"];
let arr2 = ["two", "deux", "roa"];
let arr3 = ["three", "trois", "telo"];
```

and i would like to get a result as the following :

```
let aRR = [arr1, arr2, arr3];

let result = [["one", "two", "three"],["un", "deux", "trois"],["ray", "roa", "telo"]]
```

how can i achieve that?
(i tried so many thins but didn't work out)
a generic way would be great. thank you

Comment: You will have to code something to do that, there is nothing built in that will do it.

Comment: try result.push(arr1) and then do the same for arr2 and 3